# When IntentService starts does Application object start?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service, android-lifecycle, android-intentservice

I want to understand `Application` object lifecycle in `Android`, especially with `IntentService`.

If `IntentService` starts, does `Application` object start along with it? And what is the exact sequence for this? Finally, when will it be destroyed in this case?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `Application` instance is a singleton. Whenever Android creates an OS process to host an Android component (`Activity, Service, BroadcastReceiver, Provider`) of an application, it performs the following:

- Creates a new `Application` instance (which will call the constructor of that class)
- Calls `onCreate()` on the new `Application` instance

After that, Android then instantiates the necessary component (which calls the constructor for that component) and then calls `onCreate()` on that component.

In the example of `IntentService`, you should see the following (in order):

- Create new instance of `Application` (calling constructor of `Application`)
- Call `Application.onCreate()`
- Create new instance of `IntentService` (calling constructor of `IntentService`)
- Call `IntentService.onCreate()`

If your `IntentService` completes and is stopped, Android will eventually call `onDestroy()` on the `IntentService` instance. At this point, if there are no other active components in the OS process, Android may decide to kill the OS process, or it may leave the OS process around for awhile.

If Android needs to start your `IntentService` again and there is still a live OS process for your application, Android will not create a new OS process it will just reuse the existing one. In this case, the `Application` instance already exists, so Android does not need to instantiate a new one. Android just creates a new instance of `IntentService`, calls `IntentService.onCreate()` and starts the `IntentService`.

The `Application` instance is never destroyed. When Android wants to shutdown the OS process hosting your application, it just kills the process.

Comment: @Onik Killing an OS process does not cause the destruction (in an object sense) of the `Application` instance. The OS just makes the process "go away". There is no guarantee that any "clean up" will actually occur. You will also notice that there is no `onDestroy()` method in the `Application` class.

Comment: Correct. _"Never destroyed"_, without clarification seemed confusing to me, and probably might for someone else.